# change the item background color on scrolldown

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want the items to change background color as the user scrolls down.

I tried achieving it with jQuery with no luck.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {
    $(".header-wrap").stop().animate({
      zoom: 1
    });
  } else {
    $(".header-wrap").stop().animate({
      zoom: 2
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.content-wrap {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
}
.header-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrap">Not affected</div>
<div class="header-wrap">hello
  <br/>hello
  <br/>hello
  <br/>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cXxDW/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can just use

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

instead of

```
window.scrollY
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/cXxDW/159/)